# How can I make CLIENT-CERT SSL renegotiation work in Jetty?

Tags: java, servlets, ssl, jetty, client-certificates

I have a webapp that has a public https area, and a private https protected with client certificate using SSL renegotiation.
This configuration works correctly (not without a lot of work) in Tomcat 7 with APR.

Now I'm working with Jetty and I've tried everything but I can't make it work.

The client certificates dialog never appears in the browser, and I always get an HTTP 403 error.

My environment is:
jdk 1.7.0.02
jetty 9.0.0.M3 launched from Eclipse Helios with m2e. (jetty:run)

The server appears to have SSL renegotiation enabled, testing it as indicated [here](http://blog.ivanristic.com/2009/12/testing-for-ssl-renegotiation.html), so I'm quite sure there are no problems with the SSL Renegotiation Security issues.

I've overrided ClientCertAuthenticator (to be able to debug) and created a custom LoginService, and it looks like the X509Cert never appears in the request.

Looks like the SSL renegotiation is never triggered, and authentication fails, because there is not a certificate in the request.

The LoginService configured simply returns true to every validation. I can post them too, if asked, but the important methods never get called.

If I use needCLientCert or wantClientCert application works ok, but then browser asks for the certificate in the public area.

My configuration files:

web.xml: http://pastebin.com/LQ3RcWY4

jetty.xml: http://pastebin.com/iE9xqcLq

jetty-context.xml: http://pastebin.com/rcSsBfRW

pom.xml (jetty part): http://pastebin.com/wBLATggq

Am I missing something obvious? I don't know. I've searched a lot and tried many possible configurations, but, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Jetty+Security

Work around by turning off SSL renegotiation in Jetty. If using JVM > 1.6u19 setAllowRenegotiate(true) may be called on connectors

You open your server to the BEAST attack though.